# publishOn vs subscribeOn when making a blocking call in Reactor

Tags: project-reactor, reactive-streams

In the blog post [Flight of the Flux 3](https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/13/flight-of-the-flux-3-hopping-threads-and-schedulers), the authors suggest wrapping a synchronous blocking call in a `Mono` with a `subscribeOn` call, as shown in this snippet from the article:

```
final Flux<String> betterFetchUrls(List<String> urls) {
  return Flux.fromIterable(urls)
    .flatMap(url -> 
             //wrap the blocking call in a Mono
             Mono.fromCallable(() -> blockingWebClient.get(url))
             //ensure that Mono is subscribed in an boundedElastic Worker
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    ); //each individual URL fetch runs in its own thread!
}
```

But earlier in the same post, they show that you can use `publishOn` to ensure a blocking call is done on a separate thread:

```
Flux.fromIterable(firstListOfUrls) //contains A, B and C
    .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .map(url -> blockingWebClient.get(url))
    .subscribe(body -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName + " from first list, got " + body));
```

Given that, why not just implement the `betterFetchUrls` method using `publishOn` directly?

```
final Flux<String> betterFetchUrls(List<String> urls) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(urls)
        .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .map(url -> blockingWebClient.get(url));
}
```

Isn't that simpler? The Reference Manual for Reactor in [Appendix C](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking) also does the wrapped call in a `Mono` with a `subscribeOn`, so I presume there must be a reason that's preferred, but I can't figure out what that reason might be.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually fine, expect for you have to use a `flatMap` instead of a `map` as:

```
final Flux<String> betterFetchUrls(List<String> urls) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(urls)
        .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .flatMap(url -> blockingWebClient.get(url));
}
```

Both `subscribeOn` and `publishOn` do a context switch, so both are pretty expensive operations (I have no idea on which one is more expensive though, would love some documentation around this). But the usual accepted way to make blocking calls is using a `subscribeOn` as mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post aims at explaining the two operators.
Also, the reason why `subscribeOn` could be preferable in that second snippet is exposed in the text:

> But what if that url-fetching method was written by somebody else, and they regrettably forgot to add the publishOn? Is there a way to influence the Thread upstream?

Yes, the `publishOn` solution might be easier to read and follow, when that's available. That said, if you have no control about the outer sequence and you just want to return a `Mono` that ensures its work is done on a thread of your chosing, `.subscribeOn` is going to provide more guarantees.